# Android : Hidiing activity below while opening Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-drawable

I have created an activity which extends FragmentActivity. This main activity creates a Facebook Login Fragment. This is how it looks:

[image]

After this, I used the Google Navigation Drawer example to show up a Navigation Drawer. I was able to do that but when I open up my Naviagtion, the activity below is not getting deactivated (or hidden). This is how it looks:

[image]

Should I manually hide everything on the activity after opening up the navigation drawer ? Isnt there an automatic way thru navigation drawer handles this ?

My layout XML looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    .
    .
    .

    </DrawerLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/facebookLoginFragment"
        .
        .
    </fragmet>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my mainactivity extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: Hi @paypalcomp did you got the solution for this problem ? if so please reply.